# pageLoad event of jquery does not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

here is my code

```
<script src="admin/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jQuery-ui-1.10.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {

        alert('asdf');   

    }

</script>

<body>

</body>
```

when i left blank the body tag alert does not show up. I don't get it how to deal with it. Am i doing any thing wrong?
any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Update**

1) this page is not working

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script src="admin/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jQuery-ui-1.10.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert('asdf');
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2) this page is working, i realize that this page contains script manager if i delete from    this page , page will not work . why?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script src="admin/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jQuery-ui-1.10.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        alert('asdf');           
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="240">
    <tr>
        <td height="10">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="SMHome" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this: http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function on your load event. the following will work:

```
<body onload='pageLoad()'>
```

Alternatively you can let jquery handle the event for you, as Justin has already posted, i.e:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        alert('asdf');   

    });

</script>
```

Comment: i also want to know why this is happening. why pageLoad() event sometimes working and sometimes not.

Comment: You need to call the function on your load event. It will always work if you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call or wire your function to handle any events. jQuery has a very easy built-in way of calling code once the page is ready:

```
$(function(){
    alert('asdf');
});
```

Comment: @AijazChauhan - It's hard to say without seeing your markup, but I'm guessing the function is getting registered as a handler somewhere.

Comment: should i post my both page ? one which is working fine and other is not working

Comment: @AijazChauhan - It would certainly help.

Comment: @AijazChauhan - Your second example has a ScriptManager on the page. I'm guessing the pageLoad handler is registered somewhere in the CodeBehind file. Look for a call to ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript